# How to remove this part of the string and compare it with a list if it matches?

Tags: python, string, list

I got this string:

```
Last login: Thu Jul 16 11:11:11 2018
```

in a website.

So how do I remove this part: `11:11:11` from the string?
Because I got a list that contains other Dates, but without the time.

```
self.list = [Thu Jul 16 2018, Wed Jul 15 2018]
```

So I have to remove the time from the first string and compare it with the list.
I would compare it like this: `if string in self.list:`

Comment: `re.sub(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} ','',str)`, definitely a dupe somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after seeing the comment on this post i figured out that this is a more suitable solution.

```
    string = "Last login: Thu Jul 16 11:11:11 2018"
    list_of_element = string.split(" ")
    del list_of_element[0] 
    # ^ it will delete "Last". The list is now => ['login:', 
    # 'Thu', 'Jul', '16', '11:11:11', '2018']

    del list_of_element[0] 
    # ^ it will delete "login:". The list is now => ['Thu', 'Jul', '16', 
    # '11:11:11', '2018']
    for item in list_of_element:
        if len(item) >= 8:
            list_of_element.remove(item)

     new_string = " ".join(list_of_element) 
     # .join will glue together the string elements of the list
```

and string will be "Thu Jul 16 2018". The number 8 is based on the length of the item you want to delete.

Comment: if you have `Last login: ` in the string, you'll want to use `del content[0], content[1], content[7]`

Comment: okay thanks, what if the string is Thu 16 11:11:11 EST 2018?

Comment: and I want to have the above Example? So from Thu 16 11:11:11 EST 2018? to "Thu Jul 16 2018" ?

Comment: the index in the "del" command is clearly hardcoded because i thought that the data parsed in this code would be pretty clear. With that being said, since the "11:11:11"   is most probabily the longest item in the list (after splitting the string) you colud delete the item only if it exceed a certain length

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not an ortodox method but will be valid for your example:

```
# Declare function for know if is hour
def is_hour(s):
    return len(s.split(":")) > 2
s = "Last login: Thu Jul 16 11:11:11 2018"
s_filtered = [ss for ss in s.split(" ") if not is_hour(ss)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "Last login: Thu Jul 16 11:11:11 2018"

list = string.split(' ')

new_str = ''

for i in range(len(list)):
    if i == 0 or i == 1 or i == 5: #Removes addition of the time and last login: to the new string
        continue
    new_str = new_str + list[i] + ' '
```

The above code obtains the string you need from the given data.